# Interpreting Density Plot Output

Tags: plotting

I used density plot to plot a (rather) complicated function on X-Y axes. The domain of interest is [0,1]*[0,1]. The output I get however is blank on the boundaries and so am unsure about how to interpret the plot. Here is the code am using

```
Clear[f, g, h, v, p, r, l, jac, u1, u2, u3, u4, G, x, y, z, sol, \
xinit, yinit, zinit, plotfunc0, plotfunc1]
(*d=1-h, e=r=((1-v)/2)*)
r = 0.9;    (*Recombination parameter*)
G = \
{{50, 52, 56, 36, 32, 30}, {48, 50, 54, 34, 30, 28}, {44, 46, 50, 30, 
   26, 24}, {64, 66, 70, 10, 6, 4}, {68, 70, 74, 14, 10, 8}, {70, 72, 
   76, 16, 12, 10}};
u1[v_, h_] = (G[[1, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 ) +  G[[1, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
   G[[1, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[1, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
   G[[1, 5]]*h*v +  G[[1, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2;
u2[v_, h_] = 
 G[[2, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[2, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
  G[[2, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[2, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
  G[[2, 5]]*h*v +  G[[2, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2; 
u3[v_, h_] = 
 G[[3, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[3, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
  G[[3, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[3, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
  G[[3, 5]]*h*v +  G[[3, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2;
u4[v_, h_] = 
  G[[4, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[4, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
   G[[4, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[4, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
   G[[4, 5]]*h*v +  G[[4, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2;
u5[v_, h_] = 
  G[[5, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[5, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
   G[[5, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[5, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
   G[[5, 5]]*h*v +  G[[5, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2;
u6[v_, h_] = 
   G[[6, 1]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[6, 2]]*(1 - h)*v + 
    G[[6, 3]]*(1 - h)*(1 - v)/2 +  G[[6, 4]]*h*(1 - v)/2 +  
    G[[6, 5]]*h*v +  G[[6, 6]]*h*(1 - v)/2;
ualpha[v_, 
   h_] = ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u1[v, h]) + ((1 - h)*v*
     u2[v, h]) + ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u3[v, h]) + (h*((1 - v)/2)*
     u4[v, h]) + (h*v*u5[v, h]) + (h*((1 - v)/2)*u6[v, h]);
ud[v_, h_] = ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u1[v, h]) + ((1 - h)*v*
     u2[v, h]) + ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u3[v, h]);
uh[v_, h_] = (h*(1 - v)/2*u4[v, h]) + (h*v*u5[v, h]) + (h*((1 - v)/2)*
     u6[v, h]);
uR[v_, h_] = ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u1[v, h]) + (h*((1 - v)/2)*u4[v, h]);
uV[v_, h_] = ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u2[v, h]) + (h*v*u5[v, h]);
uE[v_, h_] = ((1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u3[v, h]) + (h*((1 - v)/2)*u6[v, h]);
F1[v_, h_] = ((1 - r)*(1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u1[v, h]/ualpha[v, h]) + (r*
     ud[v, h]*uR[v, h]/((ualpha[v, h])^2)) - (1 - h)*((1 - v)/2);
F2[v_, h_] = ((1 - r)*(1 - h)*v*u2[v, h]/ualpha[v, h]) + (r*ud[v, h]*
     uV[v, h]/((ualpha[v, h])^2)) - (1 - h)*v;
F3[v_, h_] = ((1 - r)*(1 - h)*((1 - v)/2)*u3[v, h]/ualpha[v, h]) + (r*
     ud[v, h]*uE[v, h]/((ualpha[v, h])^2)) - (1 - h)*((1 - v)/2);
F4[v_, h_] = ((1 - r)*h*((1 - v)/2)*u4[v, h]/ualpha[v, h]) + (r*
     uh[v, h]*uR[v, h]/((ualpha[v, h])^2)) - h*((1 - v)/2);
F5[v_, h_] = ((1 - r)*h*v*u5[v, h]/ualpha[v, h]) + (r*uh[v, h]*
     uV[v, h]/((ualpha[v, h])^2)) - h*v;
hvG[v_, h_] = F5[v, h]/(h*v);
heG[v_, h_] = ( -F1[v, h] - F2[v, h] - F3[v, h] - F4[v, h] - 
     F5[v, h])/(h*(1 - v)/2);
net[v_, h_] = (-heG[v, h] + hvG[v, h]);
DensityPlot[net[v, h], {v, 0, 1}, {h, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14]]
```

AM basically interested in seeing how net(v,h) function defined in the code varies as I change the value of v and h from 0 to 1. The function net(v,h) has zero in the denominator near the boundaries where v and h are either 0 or 1. So, I think may be I understand why there is a blank space at the boundary. However, even at values of h at 0.8, I encounter some blank regions which I do not understand or know how to interpret. Any comments on how to use or interpret DensityPlot function output are[image] greatly appreciated.

Comment: Blank means that the values can't be plotted, either because they are not numeric, or because they are outside of the plot range. You can try `PlotRange->All` to fix it.

Comment: Do `Plot3D[net[v, h], {v, 0, 1}, {h, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-35, 25}]` to get an impression of function net. `PlotLegends -> Automatic`  in DensityPlot chooses a range it regards interessting. Choose an other range.